# Electroplating reaction

Tags: electrochemistry

In electroplating, can a galvanic cell substitute the direct current supply? The process is to change iron metal to a silver one, but a galvanic cell is connected to the two electrodes.

Comment: Chroumium metal is involved in the galvanic cell

Comment: Anything with an electrical current, whether from a galvanic cell or battery etc., is fine for electroplating. It would help if you were more specific.